# What version of Divinity is the most recent?

Tags: version-differences, divinity-original-sin-2

Someone I follow started to play a Divinity game and I decided now was the time I wanted to give this a shot so I thought I'd go and buy it from steam, however, in doing so I've run into a bit of an issue. What version is the version I should be buying, or rather, what is the most recent version?

I can see

- Divinity: Original Sin 2

but I can also see:

- Beyond Divinity
- Divine Divinity
- Divinity II: Developer's Cut
- Divinity: Original Sin - Enhanced Edition
- Divinity: Original Sin 2 - Definitive Edition
- Divinity: Original Sin 2 - Divine Ascension

My question is what version is the one I should be buying and what is the difference between them all?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Divinity is a series of video games. Of those, Divinity: Original Sin 2 is the latest entry.

- **Divine Divinity** is the first game in the series, an action RPG that was released in 2002
- **Beyond Divinity** is also an action RPG, released in 2004, which takes place 20 years after the events of Divine Divinity
- **Divinity II** is another action RPG, released in 2009, and takes place about a thousand years after Divine Divinity
- **Divinity: Original Sin** is a prequel to Divine Divinity and, unlike the original, uses a turn-based combat system. The game was released in 2014 and takes place thousands of years before Divine Divinity
- **Divinity: Original Sin II** is the latest game in the series, a turn-based RPG released in 2017 that takes place four years after Beyond Divinity.
- **Divinity: Original Sin II - Definitive Edition** is a free update to Divinity: Original Sin II, not a separate re-release. This update mostly consists of small balance changes, some additional bits of lore, and more voiced lines.
- **Divinity: Original Sin II - Divine Ascension** is "DLC" for Divinity: Original Sin II, consisting of digital soundtrack, art books, and maps.
- Additonally, **Divinity: Dragon Commander** is another game in the series, a mix of strategy and action RPG released in 2013.

Comment: I'd add that the recent games that are well renowned are Divinity: Original Sin 1 and 2. The 2 is a clear improvement on the first but lot of people would tell you that it is still worth it to play D:OS1 first.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked about Steam, this is the complete version:
[Divinity: Original Sin 2 - Definitive_Edition](https://store.steampowered.com/app/435150/Divinity_Original_Sin_2__Definitive_Edition/).

[Divinity: Original Sin 2 - Divine_Ascension](https://store.steampowered.com/app/715950/Divinity_Original_Sin_2__Divine_Ascension/) this is only concept arts and soundtrack DLC for the game, it doesn't add any gameplay content.

Other things you mentioned are previous games in series:

- Divine Divinity (2002);
- Beyond Divinity (2004);
- Divinity II: Developer's Cut (2009);
- Divinity: Original Sin - Enhanced Edition (2014).

All of games in series are also included in this bundle [DIVINITY: ORIGINAL SIN 2 - ETERNAL EDITION](https://store.steampowered.com/sub/207168/)